# VBA .SaveAs and Overwrite

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to save a file and if it already exists, I'd like to overwrite it... I've looked on the documentation for [.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) and I'm not sure I'm understanding, I thought it'd be under the `ConflictResolution:=` but I can't seem to find it under there. I want it to **not** inform the user that it is overwriting the file as well as this is just a temporary saved file

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SaveFilePath & "\FILE.xls", FileFormat:=51
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I typically do in this scenario is just check to see if it exists already, and if it does, delete it...

```
If Dir(sFilename) <> "" Then Kill sFilename
```

Comment: You're a god's send, this works great!

Comment: Keep in mind that if the file is currently open this will throw an exception, but just trying to overwrite it when it's open will also throw an exception.

Comment: Yea, I saw that too... It's a little unfortunate, but it still works for my situation as the file is closed and only in rare cases will it ever be used again. Just need a temporary save location so I can attach it to an email and send it off after some edits were made

Comment: I have came to this thread would like to know if there is a away to save as and over write and still work if the excel file is opened for a bit